# Funciones con nombres iguales y distintos parametros - JS

Tags: javascript, funciones, recursión

Tengo este código de JS

```js
function rango(inicio, fin) {
  let rango = [];
  for (let elemento = inicio; elemento <= fin; elemento++) {
    rango.push(elemento);
  }
  return rango;
}

function rango(fin) {
  return rango(0, fin);
}
```

El programa debe poder llamar a la función en ambos casos de un parámetro o dos. Pero al llamar a la variante que tiene solo un parámetro se llama recursivamente generando un

> InternalError: too much recursion

¿Sugerencias?

Comment: **NO** deben haber **NUNCA**, pero **NUNCA** pero **JAMAS** de los **NUNCA** funciones repetidas, si ya de por si tener variables repetidas no es del todo bueno dependiendo del caso, tener funciones repetidas es unas 10 vecez peor, de hecho nunca me he preguntado que pasa si hay una funcion repetida, no se si al final la ultima se sobreescribe y funciona o simplemente te manda un error, el punto es que... no sabemos cual es el resultado que esperas, es decir recuerda que esto no es `java` en `java` pueden haber metodos con distintos parametros pero igual nombre, en `JS` NO.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas el resultado esperado, pues por el momento nos dices que hay funciones repetidas pero no nos indicas ni que quieres hacer con ellas ni que es lo que esperas que hagan, aparte veo que deseas usar recursividad, porfavor edita la pregunta y coloca esta información para poder nosotros ayudarte.

Comment: El paradigma de sobreescritura de signaturas no es válido en JavaScript. **Es raro que haya funcionado** y envíe errores. Yo esperaría que simplemente **se muera en silencio** posiblemente *mucha recursión* traduce que no pudo identificar qué se llamaba y agotó "la pila de procesos" tratando de enlazar. Lee [Funciones — bloques de código reutilizables](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Functions)

Answer (score 1):

Como bien lo han mencionado en los comentarios no puedes aplicar polimorfismo a las funciones en Javascript, pero puedes usar la misma función y pasarle los parámetros que necesitas y según la cantidad de parámetros recibidos puedes ajustar tu lógica para lograr ese "polimorfismo", un ejemplo sería los siguiente:

```js
function rango(inicio, fin) {
    const rango = [];

    if (arguments.length === 1) {
      fin = inicio;
      inicio = 0;
    }

    for (let elemento = inicio; elemento <= fin; elemento++) {
        rango.push(elemento);
    }

    return rango;
}

console.log(rango(5, 10));
console.log(rango(5));
```

Acá hacemos uso de **arguments** que es una utilidad propia de Javascript en donde se almacenan todos los argumentos pasados a una función y según la longitud podrías ajustar tu lógica.

Answer (score 1):

No uses dos funciones, solo generaras problemas de `namespaces`, en su lugar simplemente usa la funcion como la tienes y comprueba primero si el ultimo parametro existe:

```js
function rango (  inicio ,  fin ) {
  const start = fin ? inicio : 0;
  const fins = fin ? fin : inicio;
  const rango = [];
  for (let elemento = start;  elemento <= fins ;  elemento ++) {
    rango.push (elemento);
  }
  return rango;
}

console.log(rango(2));
```

Ademas recuerda que en `javascript` no tendras problemas con tipos de datos, y aparte si no pones uno de los parametros **no te va a generar errores**, esto lo puedes aprovechar como lo hice arriba.

El resultado es que si ejecutas la funcion con 1 o 2 parametros el resultado siempre sera el correcto, pues en caso de que le pases un solo numero te generara numeros en un array del `0` a `x`, en caso de que le pases dos sera de `n` a `x`.

Ahora bien, lo que hice fue crear dos nuevas constantes:

```
const start = fin ? inicio : 0;
const fins = fin ? fin : inicio;
```

La primera servira para reconocer desde donde debemos iniciar, dependiendo de si solo se nos fueron pasado 1 parametro o dos, es decir, si el parametro `fin` esta presente entonces usamos el parametro inicio, en caso contrario comenzamos desde el `0` siempre.

La segunda constante `fins` detectara casi lo mismo que la constante `start`, nada mas que esta sera usada como el final del ciclo dependiendo de si existe el parametro `fin` o no, que en caso de no existir se usa el parametro `inicio`, de esta manera lo tomamos de `0` hasta `inicio`, que como es solo un parametro enrealidad `inicio` seria el fin.

Lo dividi en dos constantes justamente para que no te confundieras en esa parte.

luego simplemente en vez de usar las variables que usaste en el ciclo las reemplace por las nuevas dos constantes como podemos ver aqui:

```
for (let elemento = start;  elemento <= fins ;  elemento ++)
```

De esta manera no importa si ejecutas la funcion con un parametro o 2 el resultado sera el correcto.

Answer (score 0):

En javascript las funciones se pueden redefinir sobrescribiéndose, fijate en el console log cómo nunca llega a la primera versión de la función debido a que la segunda versión la reemplazó:

```js
function rango(inicio, fin) {
  console.log('soy rango primera versión con 2 parámetros')
  let rango = [];
  for (let elemento = inicio; elemento <= fin; elemento++) {
    rango.push(elemento);
  }
  return rango;
}

var r1 = rango(1, 5)
console.log(r1)

function rango(fin) {
  console.log('soy rango segunda versión con 1 parámetro')
  return rango(0, fin);
}

var r2 = rango(1, 5)
console.log(r2)
```

Para evitar que se sobrescriban las funciones se pueden declarar como constantes, ahí el error salta al intentar redefinirla:

```js
const rango = function(inicio, fin) {
  console.log('soy rango primera versión con 2 parámetros')
  let rango = [];
  for (let elemento = inicio; elemento <= fin; elemento++) {
    rango.push(elemento);
  }
  return rango;
}

var r1 = rango(1, 5)
console.log(r1)

function rango(fin) {
  console.log('soy rango segunda versión con 1 parámetro')
  return rango(0, fin);
}

var r2 = rango(1, 5)
console.log(r2)
```

Para definir una función que acepte uno o varios parámetros y reaccione de manera diferente según la cantidad ya hay otras respuestas, en el caso de esta función en particular podés usar un par de trucos:

- [valores iniciales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Parametros_por_defecto)
- [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from)
- funciones matemáticas [valor absoluto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/abs) y [valor mínimo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/min)

(*) variación del ejemplo [generador de secuencias (rangos)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from#Generador_de_secuencia_rango) en MDN

```js
const rango = function(inicio = 1, final = 1) {
  return Array.from({
    length: (Math.abs(final * 1 - inicio * 1) + 1)
  }, function(valor, indice) {
    return Math.min(final, inicio) + indice
  })
}

// un sólo parámetro
console.log( rango(5) )
// dos parámetros
console.log( rango(5, 6) )
// también funciona con los parámetros al revés...  no es un BUG es un feature(tm) 
console.log( rango(6, 3) )
```